# Binance - Suspended

Tags: exchanges, binance

I'm new to the site and tried searching but couldn't find anything related to Binance always saying "Network Congestion, Withdrawal Suspend" when trying to withdraw IOTA shares - any ideas what is going on with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is focused of a temporary issue occurring these days. A more generic question about networking congestion issues "in general" could be better.

Answer (score 1):

The volume being traded is at unprecedented levels today, and at the exact same time, the network is being hit with a spam attack. Therefore, it seems likely that binance is being overwhelmed in their network.

Comment: Thank you - it just seems that it has been "suspended" almost all the time since last week